# Travelling outside Singapore on Multiple Entry Visa after EP cancelled

Tags: visas, indian-citizens, singapore

My Singapore EP pass has been cancelled. However, I still have a valid Multiple Entry tourist visa. Can I take a short trip outside Singapore and come back?
Would it be useful to show a return ticket from Singapore to home upon arrival back in Singapore?

Comment: For completeness, what’s your nationality and why and when was your Employment Pass cancelled?

Comment: Nationality is Indian. The EP was cancelled because I decided to quit my job. However, I have had the tourist visa before the current employer issued the EP. I believe I have a short visit pass that lets me stay in the country for 30 day but not enter it again. But as I mentioned i still hold a multiple entry visa to Singapore valid till end of August this year.

Comment: The short visit pass is issued on the recommendation of the current (now past) employer.

Comment: If you had an Employment Pass you were presumably living in Singapore. If you leave, will you be able to prove to Immigration that you are re-entering as a tourist/for activities that a tourist visa allows? Are your personal circumstances the same as those stated in your Tourist visa application?

Comment: I am not sure what it means when you say activities. I will have a return ticket to India in hand and will be able to say I intend to visit and stay with friends for some time longer.

Comment: will that be sufficient?

Comment: Just an opinion, but possibly/probably No. Think about it from the Immigration Officer’s point of view - until recently you were living/working in Singapore. You have friends there, and presumably other ties. If I were the IO, I’d ask myself if you were coming back to try to stay/work and I’d want you to prove that you have a compelling reason to leave ie ties to India.